# document.on change vs element.on change

Tags: jquery

I am used to using 'on' function for capturing events but I have also worked with delegates. I was wondering what are the actual differences on using below two pieces of code? performance difference etc?

```
$(element).on('change', function(){
    // do my thing
})


$(document).on('change', element, function(){
    // do my thing here as well :)
})
```

Is it safe and efficient to use the second one all the time or are there any performance or event binding issues?

Comment: I prefer using the second method, however just be aware that if you work in a single page application that it will stack multiple on events on the document. So just make sure to add an .off before you call the .on (in single page applications) Also it doesn't have to be document, it can just be the parent container you are listening on

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-body-on-document-on/

Even though performance difference is minor, still, "document" is performing better than "element".